# How to set the width of info panel for the svg according to the width of svg dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want to put the info panel at the bottom of the svg map that I have done but what I want is the info panel width is to fill completely according to the width of svg which I have mentioned in the viewbox, so if I reduce the size of the map then also the width of the info panel should fill completely according to the width of svg.

[Sample Code](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FXMQYRXMIWD5)

Comment: Sample code for the above problem : https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FXMQYRXMIWD5

Comment: please show the code in your question - [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53496421/edit) the question and use the snippet button in the wysiwyg to enter your code

Comment: It showing some error, that's why I have added the sample link for the code. Can you please check on that link.

Comment: Sorry your question is off topic if the code is not in the question, you can add the link too but just make sure the code is in the question - this is meant to be a repository of information for future visitors and if the link rots then this question will be of no use without the code in the question

Comment: I have added the link

Comment: Put your `<div class="info_panel">` inside the `<div class="map">`. Do not create this div. Just change the `innerHTML`. Make the `.info_panel` width = 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the **width** and **margin** on .map svg instead added to **.map**, apend .info_panel to **.map** instead of body and set the **width: 100%** for .info_panel . This way the .info_panel width will always be 100% size of the map.

**Snippet:**

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css'>
<style>.p {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.map svg {
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
  .map {
    width: 550px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
.map g {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 1;

}

.map g:hover {
  fill: #fc0 !important;
  cursor: help;
}

.info_panel {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .8);
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.info_panel::first-line {
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="map">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Livello_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 -21.6 761 919" style="enable-background:new 0 -21.6 761 919;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="sar">
      <polygon class="st0" points="193,463 203.6,472.3 210,472.3 207.2,482 217.6,491.5 221.5,524.9 213.6,537.5 218.8,559.4
                                   206.2,599.4 209.1,610.6 198.5,623.2 187,611.7 170.8,617.6 173.8,629.1 157.4,637.6 139.2,619.5 138.3,591.7 149.8,564.9
                                   141.1,561.1 143.2,550.4 142.1,513.4 136.4,507.9 129,505.7 128.1,502.8 136.4,498.3 133.6,482 132.6,479 141.1,474.9 143.2,487.5
                                   154.5,489.4 167.9,484.7 184,469.4  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="sic">
      <polygon class="st0" points="374.4,704.6 363.7,710.2 365.6,729.2 370.8,741.8 400.2,750.4 430.8,770.3 449.7,778.2 467.9,785.6
                                   477.6,799.1 494.8,802.9 510.9,810.6 515.5,805.6 510.1,797.2 522.6,780.1 516.6,763.8 508.2,760.7 512,736.1 521.6,725.5
                                   530.9,694.8 513.7,694 507.3,703.5 497.5,696.7 483.2,705.5 469.8,710.2 448.8,706.5 439.2,713.1 421.2,704.6 410.5,705.5
                                   410.5,695.9 391.6,696.7 393.5,709.3 385,711.2  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="cal">
      <polygon class="st0" points="535.3,568.9 549.7,566.8 557.5,568.4 580.4,558.3 588.3,561.9 582.8,580.1 587.8,593.9 596.8,591.7
                                   606.2,602.6 615.4,602.1 616.6,627.5 621.1,634.1 621.7,647.5 605.5,643.4 589.5,655.9 589.9,685 573.9,696.5 563.2,718 542.1,718
                                   537.7,707.1 538,704.6 537.2,698.9 543.7,690.2 550.3,668.3 545.2,663.4 565.1,654 553.9,610.2 543.7,597.2  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="bas">
      <polyline class="st0" points="601.7,531.5 594.6,517.6 583.9,510.9 573.6,513.4 562.7,498.3 554.7,497 551.1,487.2 545.2,482.3
                                    538.9,485.6 527.8,485.3 527.8,498.6 518.5,502.5 524.9,524.7 542.4,549.6 537.7,552 530.3,566.2 530.3,566.2 534.7,568.9
                                    549.8,566.8 557.5,568.7 570.2,562.7 581.3,558 588.9,561.6 590.2,556.4 601.7,531.5  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="pug">
      <polygon class="st0" points="495.8,462 495.1,451.6 501.6,439.3 506.3,426.9 506.3,426.5 512,428.1 558.6,429.1 565.1,437.9
                                   547.1,448.5 610,486.6 635.1,505.7 659,514.3 667.4,531.5 685.5,542.1 689.6,551.7 683.6,564 685.5,576.3 663.8,570.9 658.1,560.2
                                   655.1,548.7 636,544.9 620.7,535.3 617.9,531.5 601.7,531.5 594.6,517.6 583.9,510.9 573.6,513.4 562.7,498.3 554.7,497
                                   551.1,487.2 545.2,482.3 538.9,485.6 512,486.3 509.5,472.6 502.5,470.4 501.6,462.3  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="cam">
      <polyline class="st0" points="430.8,479 451.6,508.7 460.5,507.9 470.9,524.1 489.6,523.2 498.6,538.3 493.9,549.6 509,555.6
                                    530,566.5 530.3,565.1 537.7,552 542.4,549.6 524.9,524.7 518.5,502.5 527.8,498.6 527.8,485.6 525.9,486 512,486.3 509.5,472.6
                                    502.5,470.4 501.6,462.3 495.8,462 477.2,466.7 462.3,457.3 450.4,464.2 436.3,463.3 439.2,472.6 430.8,479  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="mol">
      <polygon class="st0" points="506.3,426.5 494.8,423.4 486.6,416.6 486.3,416.9 486.3,417.6 479.4,429.4 470.9,433.6 466.1,425.9
                                   454.5,425.6 440.1,435.5 441.1,456 436.3,463.3 450.4,464.2 462.3,457.3 477.2,466.7 495.8,462 495.1,451.6 501.6,439.3
                                   506.3,426.9  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="abr">
      <polygon class="st0" points="408.8,362.9 411.8,367.3 410.3,379.3 404,379.6 412.7,410.2 399.9,412.2 398.7,420.7 415.9,433.3
                                   440.1,435.5 454.5,425.6 466.1,425.9 470.9,433.6 479.4,429.4 486.3,417.6 486.6,416.6 465.2,398.5 441.1,359.6 440.1,356.7
                                   420.1,362.9  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="laz">
      <polyline class="st0" points="340.7,361.5 364.9,386.7 372.5,388.6 383.1,380.8 391.9,373 408.4,362.7 411.8,367.3 410.3,379.3
                                    404,379.6 412.7,410.2 399.9,412.2 398.7,420.7 415.9,433.3 440.1,435.5 441.1,456 436.3,463.3 439.2,472.6 430.8,479 392.4,471.5
                                    352.2,439.8 346.7,426.2 334.1,419.8 321.6,395.8 319.6,394.9 323.2,380.5 331.4,377.1 330.4,362.1 340.7,361.5  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="umb">
      <polygon class="st0" points="408.1,362.9 391.9,373 383.1,380.8 372.5,388.6 364.9,386.7 340.7,361.5 340,337 352.6,331.2
                                   348.2,316.8 359.4,301.6 362.7,312.3 384,315.9 393.9,359.9 405.6,362.9  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="mar">
      <polyline class="st0" points="359.4,301.6 362.7,312.3 384,315.9 393.9,359.9 405.6,362.9 420.1,362.9 439.2,357.2 440.4,356.4
                                    427.7,310.1 404,297.5 392.4,282.3 382.6,278.2 382.3,277.9 380.9,286.6 370.3,282 358.8,283.4 352.2,291.6 359.4,301.6  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="tos">
      <polygon class="st0" points="244.4,361.5 254,357.8 260.4,352.8 262.3,363.2  "/>
      <polygon class="st0" points="247.7,273.2 247.1,262.9 236.5,252.4 235.2,242 249.1,240.7 261.4,254 272.3,255.2 277.3,264.5
                                   289.3,262.9 306,268.9 315.1,259.8 332.3,268.6 336.6,284.1 343.7,291 352.2,291.6 359.4,301.6 348.2,316.8 352.6,331.2 340,337
                                   340.7,361.5 330.4,362.1 331.4,377.1 323.2,380.5 319.6,394.9 319.6,395.3 305.5,393 298,394.9 298.9,383.4 287.4,361.5
                                   277.8,348.1 268.3,349.8 272,334.7 262.3,316.7 254,277.1 247.7,273.5  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="emi">
      <polygon class="st0" points="382.3,277.9 380.9,286.6 370.3,282 358.8,283.4 352.2,291.6 343.7,291 336.6,284.1 332.3,268.6
                                   315.1,259.8 306,268.9 289.3,262.9 277.3,264.5 272.3,255.2 261.4,254 249.1,240.7 235.2,242 221.2,241.4 217.9,227.5 205.4,224.8
                                   205.9,217.1 212.5,218.8 212.8,211.4 216.3,208.6 212.5,202.1 219.2,192.2 249.3,190.3 280.3,208.3 289.6,203.7 290.7,201.8
                                   314.2,207.9 319.6,205.3 332,213.6 343.8,213.3 364.9,217.1 362.7,221.2 365.6,256.5 376.3,275.4  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="fri">
      <polyline class="st0" points="398.8,159.1 398.7,158.8 396.5,149.9 390.5,144.7 376.8,146.3 369.5,134.5 372.2,123.1 364.3,110.1
                                    384,92.3 383.7,83.9 384,83.9 425.8,90.2 431.8,96.7 414.3,106.3 417.4,115.1 427.7,115.1 420.1,130.4 428.6,135.9 427.7,145.7
                                    442,153.1 436.3,161.9 428.6,153.1 420.1,153.1 405,148.5 403.1,156.9 399.1,159.1  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="ven">
      <polygon class="st0" points="398.8,159.1 376.3,171.2 374.4,161.9 363.7,173.1 359.9,186.5 372.5,203.7 364.6,216.8 343.8,213.3
                                   332,213.6 319.6,205.3 305.2,190 289.3,179.1 289,148.2 291.5,145.7 291.5,146 307.6,149.6 315.1,137.8 332.3,133.2 344.8,116.1
                                   337.8,108.2 342.6,93.5 361.2,86.1 371.7,75.5 371.7,75.2 380.9,83.6 383.7,83.9 384,92.3 364.3,110.1 372.2,123.1 369.5,134.5
                                   376.8,146.3 390.5,144.7 396.5,149.9 398.7,158.8  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="tre">
      <polygon class="st0" points="365.6,70.2 358.2,51 340,57.7 313.2,56.6 299.7,72.1 289.3,64.4 280,65.1 275.7,81.4 282.5,106.3
                                   279.5,116.1 275.4,126 279.4,138.4 288.5,138.9 293.2,143.8 291.5,145.7 291.5,146 307.6,149.6 315.1,137.8 332.3,133.2
                                   344.8,116.1 337.8,108.2 342.6,93.5 361.2,86.1 371.7,75.5 371.7,75.2  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="lom">
      <polygon class="st0" points="276.1,81.7 282.5,106.3 279.5,116.1 275.4,126 279.4,138.4 288.5,138.9 293.2,143.8 289,148.2
                                   289.3,179.1 305.2,190 319.6,205.3 314.2,207.9 290.7,201.8 289.6,203.7 280.3,208.3 249.3,190.3 219.2,192.2 212.5,202.1
                                   216.3,208.6 212.8,211.4 212.5,218.8 205.9,217.1 205.9,216.1 193.1,195.6 182.9,193.4 179.9,169.6 190.8,165.4 181,138.9
                                   187.3,127.2 178.5,104.5 194.7,111 198.5,132.3 205.4,129.5 204.3,116.1 213.6,105.5 218.8,87.4 227.2,87.4 236.8,102.7
                                   247.1,95.7 257.8,104.5 262.3,98.9 252.1,86.4 257.8,77.8 275.7,81.4  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="lig">
      <polyline class="st0" points="124.7,253.6 145.1,254.9 148.5,243.9 156.1,229.5 169.2,233.8 176,228.6 187.6,230.5 194.4,223.1
                                    205.4,224.8 217.9,227.5 221.2,241.4 235.2,242 236.5,252.4 247.1,262.9 247.7,273.2 247.7,273.5 206.2,247.5 184,242.9
                                    171.7,247.5 160.5,259.2 154.5,270.7 124.7,281.4 116.5,272.6 124.7,253.6  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="pie">
      <polygon class="st0" points="110.6,153.1 129.3,155.6 139.6,149.9 145.7,151.2 151.1,146.6 147,128.8 147,122.5 177.7,85.5
                                   178.5,104.5 187.3,127.2 181,138.9 190.8,165.4 179.9,169.6 182.9,193.4 193.1,195.6 205.9,216.1 205.4,224.8 194.4,223.1
                                   187.6,230.5 176,228.6 169.2,233.8 156.1,229.5 148.5,243.9 145.1,254.9 124.7,253.6 88.7,239.3 86.9,219.1 101.3,205.9
                                   89.6,198.2 86.9,186.5 80,181 106.8,169.3  "/>
    </g>
    <g id="vao">
      <polygon class="st0" points="110.6,153.1 129.3,155.6 139.6,149.9 145.7,151.2 151.1,146.6 147,128.8 147,122.5 130.7,117
                                   103.2,122.5 93.4,131.3 99.4,137 99.4,141.7  "/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>


<script src='//static.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-41c52890748cd7143004e05d3c5f786c66b19939c4500ce446314d1748483e13.js'></script>

<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script >
var regions = [
{
    "region_name": "Lombardia",
    "region_code": "lom",
    "population": 9794525 },

{
    "region_name": "Campania",
    "region_code": "cam",
    "population": 5769750 },

{
    "region_name": "Lazio",
    "region_code": "laz",
    "population": 5557276 },

{
    "region_name": "Sicilia",
    "region_code": "sic",
    "population": 4999932 },

{
    "region_name": "Veneto",
    "region_code": "ven",
    "population": 4881756 },

{
    "region_name": "Emilia-Romagna",
    "region_code": "emi",
    "population": 4377487 },

{
    "region_name": "Piemonte",
    "region_code": "pie",
    "population": 4374052 },

{
    "region_name": "Puglia",
    "region_code": "pug",
    "population": 4050803 },

{
    "region_name": "Toscana",
    "region_code": "tos",
    "population": 3692828 },

{
    "region_name": "Calabria",
    "region_code": "cal",
    "population": 1958238 },

{
    "region_name": "Sardegna",
    "region_code": "sar",
    "population": 1640379 },

{
    "region_name": "Liguria",
    "region_code": "lig",
    "population": 1565127 },

{
    "region_name": "Marche",
    "region_code": "mar",
    "population": 1545155 },

{
    "region_name": "Abruzzo",
    "region_code": "abr",
    "population": 1312507 },

{
    "region_name": "Friuli-Venezia Giulia",
    "region_code": "fri",
    "population": 1221860 },

{
    "region_name": "Trentino-Alto Adige",
    "region_code": "tre",
    "population": 1039934 },

{
    "region_name": "Umbria",
    "region_code": "umb",
    "population": 886239 },

{
    "region_name": "Basilicata",
    "region_code": "bas",
    "population": 576194 },

{
    "region_name": "Molise",
    "region_code": "mol",
    "population": 313341 },

{
    "region_name": "Val d'Aosta",
    "region_code": "vao",
    "population": 127844 }];




var temp_array = regions.map(function (item) {
    return item.population;
});


$(function () {

    for (i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) 
    {
    if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(0)) 
    break;

        $('#' + regions[i].region_code).
        
        data('region', regions[i]);
    }window.CP.exitedLoop(0);

    $('.map g').mouseover(function (e) {
        var region_data = $(this).data('region');
        $('<div class="info_panel">' +
        region_data.region_name + '<br>' +
        'Population: ' + region_data.population.toLocaleString("en-UK") +
        '</div>').

        appendTo('.map');
    }).
    mouseleave(function () {
        $('.info_panel').remove();
    });

});
//# sourceURL=pen.js
</script>
</body></html>
```

- You should also move **mouseover** and **mouseleave** events to outside of the loop.no needs to put it inside loop.

[Codepen Live example](https://codepen.io/shahramwebdev/pen/QJBXMW?editors=1000)

Comment: Can you tell me where I have to make to changes on this one: https://codepen.io/brianplaza/pen/DfKsx/

Comment: @Geeky I don't see anything wrong.just when you resize the window the svg height will increase and hide the svg element.it is not responsive.i just changed the `viewBox="none"` to `viewBox="0,0, 959, 593"` resize the window to see what is different.
**max-width: 100% !important** you don't need to set !important on max-width